# I want to match the word which not starts with letter [aoieu], but the regex does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var  str = ")shenmajs-(shenmajsb)hghghg";
var reg = /\b[^aoieu][a-z]*\b/g;
str.match(reg);

//returns ["shenmajs", "shenmajsb", ")hghghg"]
```

I want to match the word which not starts with letter [aoieu]. The first item of returned array is "shenmajs" ,but  the third one is ")hghghg". I do not understand why ")" can be include the item. can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an online view of your case at regexr: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?325rr

")" is included because the regex `[^aeiou]` means *any* character that is not a, e, i, o, or u.  And that includes ")".

The way your regex worked has to do with the way the anchor `\b` is interpreted.  From [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a wor d character.
> 2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> 3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

So your first `\b` matched before the first s, *not* before the initial ")" (because you don't get an initial word boundary by Rule 1).  The first match ended with the anchor before the dash.  The next match begins at the anchor between the "(" and the s, because you can't get a match starting at the dash! (Try it!).  Your third match will now begin at the anchor between the b and the ")".  Since ")" is *not* in `[aeiou]` it is allowed to begin your next match.  And it works great, too: it is followed immediately by zero or more a-z's with an ending word boundary!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is picking `")hghghg"` because it starts with a character that is not a, o, i, e, or u, and is then followed by 0 or more letters.

Try:

```
var reg = /\b[a-z-[aeiuo]][a-z]*\b/g;
```

That is, all words starting with a letter that is not a vowel (a, e, i, o, or u), and then followed by 0 or more letters.

Comment: i know [^aoieu] means a character that is not a, o, i, e, or u, and is then followed by 0 or more letters. but "\b" means the position of a word ,which starts with "\w", doesn't it?

Comment: Ref to @ray-toal 's answer below for detail re the word boundary issue.

Comment: so, how can returned array include ")hghghg"

Comment: I agree it's not intuitive, I was surprised that the boundary was inclusive of the `)`.  But I think it comes down to because you've explicitly included a "character that is not a,e,i,o,u", it gets included in the match inside the boundary (where otherwise only /w would be included).  I've confirmed that (in .NET at least, where I'm working) this: `\b\).*\b` will capture that same match, while `\b\w*\b` does indeed drop the `)`